# Why are these particular semicolons necessary in this function definition and command-line?

Tags: bash, scripting, function, syntax

I'm preparing for the LPIC1, exam 102. This question came my way and I absolutely blanked. I knew it when I first took the quiz, now a month and a half later it's all blurred in my head.

> *What does*
>
> ```
>    function a { echo $1; } ; a a b c
> ```
>
> *output?*
>
> A. a
>
> B. a b c
>
> C. a b
>
> D. a a b c

I've tried to reproduce this function by creating a file called 'script':

```
function a { echo $1;
};
a a b c
```

saved it, gave it execute permission then tried it out:

```
$ bash script
a
$
```

So the correct answer is A, but why? Is it necessary to put an `;` after `$1`? And what's the second `;` for? Can someone please explain the syntax of this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands should have been executed on a command line like:
`function a { echo $1; } ; a a b c`

The second semicolon separates the command list into
`function a { echo $1; }`
and
`a a b c`

- The first command will create a function with the name 'a' which will echo the first positional parameter.
  The semicolon after `echo $1` is required to end the command list within the function,  since there is no newline to do so.
  (see also: `man bash` -> Compound Commands -> { list; } )
- The second command `a a b c` will call that function (fist a) and hand over the 'a b c' as positional parameters to that function.

Since the function only echos the 1st positional parameter, the correct answer is 'A.'.

Answer (score 0):

`a a b c` translates to `command arg1 arg2 arg3`

All you do is define a function named `a` which returns the first argument (`$1`) which happens to be "a".

The semicolon is a matter of how grouping commands with braces works in the respective shell:

```
{ commandA ; commandB ; commandC ; ... ; commandN ; }
```

Comment: About the semicolons, does it mean you add one at the end of the closing curly bracket to signal "this is the end of the function definition"?

Comment: It simply is required (or you can close the brace after a newline) - I assume to properly differentiate it from brace expansion.